# Ubuntu Screen not working after logging in

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-tweak

I have a ubuntu 20.04. After logging in, the screen gets white and shows "Oh no! Something has gone wrong, pls log out and try again" 
After log out. I get back to my login screen and then same thing happens 
I tried all the other helps from forums like updating and upgrading. But none of them worked.

I have a amd radeon 8570,i5 3rd gen. It was working perfectly some days ago. I didn't remember doing anything. Its dual booted with win 10

Any help would be great. 
If you need anything more. Pls tell

Comment: " I tried doing sudo apt-get install And some helps.": could you be more specific? Also include syspem specs, especially about graphics card and display in your question.

Comment: I tried all the other helps from forums like updating and upgrading.

Comment: I have a amd radeon 8570,i5 3rd gen. It was working perfectly some days ago. I didn't remember doing anything

Comment: Please use "edit" to add all relevant info to your question.